# Ionic 2: src from img not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

In an Ionic 2 the src from an `<img>` is not updating inside the callback from a plugin.
The template:

```
<img [src]="avatar_path" id="myimg" />
```

Using the Camera plugin, I have the following:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( imageBase64 => {
    this.avatar_path = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBase64;
},
error => {
    console.log(error)
}, {
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    destinationType: 0,
    allowEdit:true,
    sourceType: 2
})
```

nothing happens. If I set the src with plain js it works:

```
document.getElementById("myimg").src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBase64;
```

and if I set the avatar_path outside the callback, it works.

```
this.avatar_path = 'data:image/png;base64,someharcodedbase64data';
```

It seems the view is not updating inside the callback. In Ionic 1 I would try to re-render it dealing with the $scope or something like it, but I don't know what are the best practices with Ionic 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the `this.avatar_path = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBase64;` inside NgZone.

Try the following code:

```
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
...
constructor(_zone: NgZone) {
   this._zone = _zone;
}
... 
navigator.camera.getPicture( imageBase64 => {
this._zone.run(() => {
    this.avatar_path = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBase64;      
});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why? :S

Comment: If I am inside a directive too? :S

Comment: EDIT: this actually led me in the right direction and it worked. [This](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) may help. Plus you should update your syntax to current Angular 2: `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core'`